# how to play an xna live smooth streaming in XNA

Tags: xna, streaming, video-streaming

any idea how to stream from a [live smooth streaming](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming/) to an XNA app?

is that even possible?

Comment: Are you talking about on Windows, Xbox or WP7?

Answer (score 1):

For the Xbox 360 this is not possible for out of the box XNA. XBLIG indie games and apps do not have internet access so can not do any type of streaming.

The apps you do see streaming on the Xbox (Netflix and Hulu for example) are created by large companies who have partnered with Microsoft and have access to functionality that most people and companies do not. It is possible they were written in XNA but unlikely, either way the functionality exposed to those companies is not available to the general populace.

Comment: so, how are the Netflix apps built on the xbox? native code? no c# & xna? (I know xna is mainly for building games so it would not be appropriate to try using it to stream video)

Comment: I updated my answer to explain about how Netflix and Hulu are able to do what they do. XNA can be used for applications and games by the way, it's not just limited to games.